# Create DEEP immutable object in runtime

Tags: java, immutability, cglib

I need to create immutable copy of an object in runtime with Java. I made use of org.springframework.cglib.beans.ImmutableBean, which can create immutable copy of an object using CGLIB.

But the problem is that it provides "first-level" immutability: it disallows change of an input object's properties, **but** it allows to change inner objects (e.g. get collection and add an element to it or get inner object and modify it's parameters etc.)

So the question is: what's the correct way of creating deep (recursive) immutable copy of an object so that one can't change inner objects also (at any level of nesting)?

Comment: Can you make the objects final, or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: @goodguy5, no, the point is that immutability must be achieved at a run-time: I can't modify the source code of objects I'm working with.

Comment: Have you tried using the immutator object outlined here: https://javax0.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/creating-immutable-objects-run-time/

Comment: I've tried, but it also has the same issue, e.g.:
    `InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();`
    `innerClass.setName("innerClass");`
    `OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();`
    `outerClass.setName("outerClass");`
    `outerClass.setInnerClass(innerClass);`
    `OuterClass immutable = Immutable.of(outerClass);`
    `immutable.getInnerClass().setName("try");`

Comment: And it needs to be nestable? So you can't make final OuterClass immutable = Immutable.of(outerClass); Otherwise, I'm sorry I can't be more help :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may traverse the object tree and use CGLIB to make each object immutable by using interceptor which skips required methods. The tough part though is to determine all methods which modify the object's state - for each object in the tree.

```
package ut.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

public class MyTest {

    public static class Inner {
        private String data = "hello";

        public Inner() {}

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data;
        }

    }

    public static class Outer {
        private List<Inner> list = Lists.newArrayList(new Inner());

        public Outer() {}

        public List<Inner> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<Inner> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }

    public static class GetOnlyDelegatingMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
        private Object delegate;

        public GetOnlyDelegatingMethodInterceptor(Object delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                return makeImmutable(proxy.invoke(delegate, args));
            }

            if (method.getName().equals("toString")) {
                return proxy.invoke(delegate, args);
            }

            if (method.getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class)) {
                return proxy.invoke(delegate, args);
            }

            // you may check for other methods here

            // skip all others
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Object makeImmutable(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return obj;
        }

        Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
        e.setSuperclass(obj.getClass());
        e.setCallback(new GetOnlyDelegatingMethodInterceptor(obj));
        return e.create();
    }

    @Test
    public void testImmutable() {
        Outer outerImmutable = (Outer) makeImmutable(new Outer());

        // this is initial state
        assertEquals(outerImmutable.getList().toString(), "[hello]");

        // trying to set empty list
        outerImmutable.setList(new ArrayList<>());
        // but it's still the same
        assertEquals(outerImmutable.getList().toString(), "[hello]");

        // going deeper
        outerImmutable.getList().get(0).setData("bye!");
        // but still no changes
        assertEquals(outerImmutable.getList().toString(), "[hello]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it really works, thanks! But you have to handle two additional cases: final classes can't be proxified by CGLIB (e.g. String) and classes without parameterless-constructors also can't be proxified by CGLIB.

Comment: FYI: I've implemented such approach in the library: https://github.com/dtitov/CodeFreeze

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImmutableProxy` of the [reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn/reflection-util) library.

*Disclaimer: I’m one of the authors of this library!*

Example:

```java
public class Inner
{
    private String data = "hello";
    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Outer
{
    private List<Inner> list = Arrays.asList(new Inner());
    // getters and setters
}
```

```
Outer outerImmutable = ImmutableProxy.create(new Outer());
Inner firstElement = outerImmutable.getList().get(0)

// this is initial state
assertThat(firstElement.getData()).isEqualTo("hello");

// throws UnsupportedOperationException
outerImmutable.setList(…);

// throws UnsupportedOperationException
firstElement.setData("bye!");
```